# What is the Path Payment response without paths?

Tags: path-payment

When searching for path payments using the Lab, I find there is always 1 record at the end of the array which contains no intermediate paths. This is true for any currency source/destination pair and amount I've tried. In this example of XLM -> USDC, it has given me a destination amount populated from..where? I can put any `source_amount` in so it's presumably not finding actual offers to match against?

My assumption is that this is for me to feed into the `Transaction` builder, and thus create an offer. Is that right or am I way off?

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "records": [
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "12.0000000",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USDC",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GA5ZSEJYB37JRC5AVCIA5MOP4RHTM335X2KGX3IHOJAPP5RE34K4KZVN",
        "destination_amount": "2.1112437",
        "path": [
          {
            "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
            "asset_code": "MOBI",
            "asset_issuer": "GA6HCMBLTZS5VYYBCATRBRZ3BZJMAFUDKYYF6AH6MVCMGWMRDNSWJPIH"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source_asset_type": "native",
        "source_amount": "12.0000000",
        "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "destination_asset_code": "USDC",
        "destination_asset_issuer": "GA5ZSEJYB37JRC5AVCIA5MOP4RHTM335X2KGX3IHOJAPP5RE34K4KZVN",
        "destination_amount": "2.1104581",
        "path": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```